# Optimizing prime number generation code?

Tags: c#, optimization, primes

I have written the below code to calculate and output prime numbers.

The prime numbers I get are outputted on the console as well as stored in a text file.

It calculates all numbers up till a specified one.

Any suggestions on making this code run faster & more efficiently ?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long i;
        long j;    

           for (i = 3; i < 10000000; i += 2)
           {
               bool isPrime = true;

               for (j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++)
               {
                   if (i % j == 0)
                   {
                       isPrime = false;
                       break;
                   }
               }

               if (isPrime)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(i);

                   using (System.IO.StreamWriter StreamWriter = System.IO.File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\Marco\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Prime Number Generator\Prime Number Generator\bin\Debug\Prime List.txt"))
                   {
                       StreamWriter.WriteLine(i);
                   }
               }
           }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just generate all of the numbers, 2...N, for large N. This will generate all the primes, plus a few false positives. And it is quick too.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to check division only up to `sqrt(i)`, not `i/2`. (As duly noted by @I4V in comments below, `j*j < i` will be faster than `j < sqrt(i)` as square root is a very slow operation cmp. to multiplication)
2. You can use previously found prime numbers in your loop (i.e., store them in array and loop through them), as you only need to check divisibility by primes.

Only after you optimized the **algorithm**, start optimizing your code.

Comment: Thanks the following surely helped in reducing the time for the program to find all prime numbers under X.

Comment: I would write `sqrt((float)i)`; if not `i` will be implicitely casted to `double` and the computation of the square root could be up to 9 times slower depending on the architecture (see [Agner's website](http://www.agner.org/optimize/))

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker `(j*j)<i` would be much faster than `j<sqrt(i)`

Comment: @I4V: Hu, I didn't see this one... Totally agree! It will be up to 23 times faster compared to the square root condition.

Comment: 1) A sieve is much better. 2) If you use a square root, compute the *integer* square root *once* using a `double`.  By using an integer you avoid an integer-to-floating-point conversion in each comparison. You'll need `double`, because `float` starts losing precision above 24 bits (about 16 million).  Since you do it once the time taken for the square root doesn't matter.  3) If you use `j * j < i` then better use 64 bit integers for the multiplication, lest your computation will overflow already for `j >= 65536`.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you are using is called trial division, and it has time complexity O(n^2), or O(n^1.5) if you stop at the square root as @sashkello and @giuliofranco suggested. A better algorithm is the Sieve of Eratosthenes, invented over two thousand years ago, with a time complexity of O(n log log n), which is nearly O(n). The Sieve of Eratosthenes begins by making a list of all numbers from 2 to the maximum desired prime *n*, then enters an iterative phase. At each step, then smallest uncrossed number that hasn't yet been considered is identified, and all multiples of that number are crossed out; this is repeated until no uncrossed numbers remain unconsidered. All the numbers that remain uncrossed are prime.

```
function primes(n)
    sieve := makeArray(2..n, True)
    for p from 2 to n step 1
        if sieve[p]
            output p
            for i from p*p to n step p
                sieve[i] := False
```

In the `primes` function, `sieve` is the list of numbers, the uncrossed numbers are considered in ascending order when `sieve[p]` is `True` and are output as prime as they are considered, and the "crossing out" of multiples is done by the loop on *i*; the loop starts from `p*p` because all the smaller multiples have already been crossed out by smaller primes.

If you're interested in programming with prime numbers, I modestly recommend this [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog, which discusses this algorithm, gives an optimization that will double its speed, provides many other algorithms on prime numbers, and gives implementations in five languages.

Comment: I'm pretty disappointed you didn't even speak of the [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) in your essay (pretty interesting by the way), which is the algorithm of reference when it comes to optimizations (like  wheel factorization, ...). It scales in O(*N* / log log *N*) and use less memory than the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: @Kyle: The essay is introductory, and the Sieve of Atkin is far beyond introductory. I do implement the [Sieve of Atkin](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/02/19/sieve-of-atkin-improved/) and [wheel factorization](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/01/06/pritchards-wheel-sieve/) elsewhere in my blog. Beware the asymptotic complexities involved here; it is far harder than it looks to write a Sieve of Atkin or a wheel sieve that beats the Sieve of Eratosthenes in practice, despite their theoretical superiority. I'm glad you found the essay interesting, and hope you enjoyed it.

Answer (score 0):

1) End your loop at sqrt(i), not (i/2). The time you save is worth the time you need to compute the square root.

2) Don't just forget the numbers you generate. Save them into an array (at least the last ones), and then try dividing your candidate only for the number that you know are prime. If x%y==0, then either y is a prime, or there is a prime P<y so that x%P==0. And the primes less than i are approximately only i/ln(i).This means you're wasting your time by testing all the numbers, when you can already have all the primes less than i. Note that, if you do this way, you'll be much heavier on your RAM.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long i;
    int j;
    List<long> primes = new List<long>();
    primes.Add(2);
    long maxJ;

    using (System.IO.StreamWriter StreamWriter = System.IO.File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\Marco\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Prime Number Generator\Prime Number Generator\bin\Debug\Prime List.txt"))
    {
        for (i = 3; i < 10000000; i += 2)
        {
            //Compute only once, rather that at each iteration
            maxJ = (long)Math.Sqrt(i);
            for (j = 0; j < primes.Count && primes[j] <= maxJ; ++j)
            {
                if (i % primes[j] == 0)
                {
                    goto EndOfOuterLoop;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(i);
            StreamWriter.WriteLine(i);
            primes.Add(i);

            EndOfOuterLoop:
        }
    }
}
```

3) If you really want the maximum achievable speed, you should use the [AKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) or [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) algorithms, that can check whether a number is prime in polynomial time (AKS is always correct, Miller-Rabin can sometimes say that a non-prime number is prime).